# How do you get the name of a ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ref

Say you have this JSX:

```
<div ref={this.divRef}>
  <SomeComponent />
</div>
```

And you want to get the name of the ref and add it to your state, how would you do that?

Something like:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // get all the positions of the current sections
    if (this.divRef.current) {
      this.setState({
        breakpoints: [{
          name: this.divRef.current.name,
          position: this.divRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().bottom,
        }],
      }, () => {
          // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
          console.log(this.divRef.current, 'this.divRef.current')
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Refs don't have names. Do you mean the name of the property the ref is in? Or the `name` property of the DOM element the ref refers to? ([`div`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) elements don't have `name`s, they only have the [global attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes), which `name` isn't one of...) Or the tag name (`"div"` in your example)?

Comment: If it doesn't have name how you want to get it? You should assign a name

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear. I want to assign each ref a name so I can use it later on

Comment: @A7DC you need to declare constructor of reference in constructor section like  *this.divRef = React.createRef()* then you can use that reference on page anywhere using *this.divRef.current*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you've said:

> I want to assign each ref a name so I can use it later on

If you really mean the **ref**, the only reliable way I can think of to do that is with a WeakMap keyed by the ref. (Although you *could* use a Symbol-named property, more below.)

Create the WeakMap in your constructor (or in your module, I don't know how much code needs to be able to use these names);

```
this.nameMap = new WeakMap();
```

And then when you need to get/assign the name:

```
let name = this.nameMap.get(this.divRef);
if (!name) {
    name = "some appropriate name";
    this.nameMap.set(this.divRef, name);
}
```

You *could* use a Symbol-named property, to store the name on the ref object itself, but in general storing arbitrary properties on objects your code doesn't control isn't a good idea. But for completeness, you'd create the symbol in your constructor (or module):

```
this.nameKey = Symbol("refname");
```

then use it:

```
// I don't recommend this
let name = this.divRef[this.nameKey];
if (!name) {
    name = "some appropriate name";
    this.divRef[this.nameKey] = name;
}
```

But I don't recommend it. An environment with Symbol will also have WeakMap, which I'd use here.

---

**But**, if you mean the element the ref is currently referring to, you could use a [`data-*` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) for that:

```
// Assuming you've checked that `current` isn't `null`
let name = this.divRef.getAttribute("data-name");
if (!name) {
    name = "some appropriate name";
    this.divRef.setAttribute("data-name", name);
}
```

If you can assume `dataset` support, you could use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) instead:

```
// Assuming you've checked that `current` isn't `null`
let name = this.divRef.dataset.name;
if (!name) {
    name = "some appropriate name";
    this.divRef.dataset.name = name;
}
```

That said, the WeakMap solution would work just as well for elements as for refs:

```
let name = this.nameMap.get(this.divRef.current);
if (!name) {
    name = "some appropriate name";
    this.nameMap.set(this.divRef.current, name);
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you T.J! The  data-* attribute approach is what I'm looking for, I think